# Selecting a single PDF page in iOS app

Tags: ios, pdf

In my app I have a PDF with hundreds of pages.

I want the user to be able to create a new, single paged PDF and email it.

That single paged PDF will be any given page of the large PDF in the app.

How can I accomplish this?

Sending the email is simple enough:

```
- (void)email:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *emailSubject = @"subject";
    NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", sender.tag];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailSubject];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    //    [mc addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"thePDF.pdf"];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

I am just not sure how to create the 'myData' that will be the single paged PDF

Comment: here is a how I handle the PDF file: http://overactiverexburg.com/PDFWrapper.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
 - (void)emailAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *emailSubject = @"Subject";
    NSString *messageBody = @"message";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailSubject];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc addAttachmentData:[self getPage:sender.tag+1] mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"thePDF.pdf"];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (NSMutableData *)getPage:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"]]); // Create the CGPDFDocument from the URL
    if (SourcePDFDocument == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Reference to Page current Page
    CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, pageNumber);

    if (SourcePDFPage == NULL) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)outputData);
    CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
    // draw
    CGContextBeginPage(context, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, SourcePDFPage);
    CGContextEndPage(context);
    // cleanup
    CGDataConsumerRelease(consumer);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return outputData;
}
```